# How do I parse specific items from a HTML page using java?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get stock ticker-names, which are 3-4 letter codes that uniquely identify a stock. Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
 import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Alpha {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

Document doc;
try {

    // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/movers/ftse-100/").get();

    // get page title
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);

    // get all links
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href=");
    for (Element link : links) {

        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, instead of getting ALL of the links, i want to get SPECIFIC links from the webpage. For example, the HTML code of one of the pieces of data I want to get is:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="first name">
      <a href="/quote/AGK:LN">Aggreko PLC</a>
    </td>
    <td class="value">1,594.00</td>
    <td class="change up">+52.00</td>        <td class="delta up">+3.37%</td>        <td class="value">1,561,246</td>
    <td class="datetime">11:35:00</td>
  </tr>
```

With the tag /quote/AGK:LN   the data that I want to output on the screen. How do I make the program select ONLY that part of the HTML?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cssquery you just put the value
like `"a[href='blablbla']"`

so try this

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href='/quote/AGK:LN']");
```